# HTTPS request with Cocoa/objective-C 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, https

I need to make an HTTPS request from my application in order to fetch some data. I used to be able to do it using this method here

```
    -(void)Authenticate
{
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://10.84.4.2:8444/fish-mobile/GetPIN.jsp?MSISDN=12345"]];
    //NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];

}
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:       (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.responseData = nil;
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

      NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

    }
```

However this is not working since I upgraded my code, my old application that has this code still works, but if I create a new application and poste this code in I get an error around

```
  [responseData setLength:0];
```

and

```
    [responseData appendData:data];
```

It says no visible @interface for NSString declares setLength or appenddata.

Could someone tell me why this is not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like your responseData instance variable is being somehow typecasted to NSString. How is the responseData ivar defined, and are you doing any other operations on it, except for the delegate ones you just posted?

Answer (score 2):

Shorted it to this

```
-(void) testme: (NSString *) link{
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

}

And the methods are

```
    - (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", s);

}
```

Works fine